# laravel eloquent get table 1 based on search of table 2

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

**FIXED**

So after many responses to this question I finally got my real question thought out and answered but it still leaves me wondering why eloquent can't handle the issue of

A->B->C

Given an object of A accessing all B items based on a value within C (name=script)

The below solution works and because laravel has scopes keeps things clean but I feel like there should be a easier and faster solution.

```
public function scopeType($query, $type)
    {

        return $query->join('article_image_types', 'article_image_types.id', '=', 'article_images.article_image_type_id')->where('name', $type);
    }
```

if you have two tables image and image_type and I want to find all images with a specific type what would that look like in eloquent?

Say you have a type of "script" with id "1" I know I can do, from the image collection

```
where('image_type_id', '1')
```

but how would i do it so the below worked

`where('name', 'script')`

GOAL:

I want to be able to access this data easily from a blade file so something like the below using a scope

```
<input type="text" name="['image']['script']" value="{!! $article->articleimage()->type('script') !!}">
```

or even better accessing the images based on type through form model binding ['image']['script']

So this works

```
foreach($article->articleImages->all() as $item) {
            dd($item->articleimagetype->name);
        }
```

and will return "script"

But how do get only the one that says "script"

::UPDATE::

So I setup the scope but as I expected the problem I am trying to do this based on the secondary tables name so

```
$query->where('name', $type);
```

your solution would work if I wanted to do

```
$query->where('image_type_id', 1);
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in
>   'where clause' (SQL: select * from `article_images` where
>   `article_images`.`article_id` = 32 and `article_images`.`article_id`
>   is not null and `name` = script)

**UPDATE**

So doing the below produces what I want EXCEPT I don't get back a type name and i can't seem to get it back with has('articleimagetype') or has('articleimages.articleimagetype')

```
$article->articleImages()->whereHas('articleimagetype', function($query){
            $query->where('name', 'script');
        })->has('articleimagetype')->get();
```

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here

Comment: I can't get it to return only the the one that has a imagetype name of "script" it will return all three but gives a type of null for the ones that don't have script when i run the script i just added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use join:

```
\DB::table('image')
   ->join('image_type','image_type.id','=', 'image.image_type_id')
   ->where('image_type.name','=','script')
   ->get();
```

EDIT:

after your GOAL update, I see what you want. Laravel has a feature named [`query scope`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#query-scopes) that will let you easily find the data the way you are trying to.

In your `Articleimage` model, create a scope:

```
public function scopeType($query, $type)
{
    return $query->join('article_image_type','article_image_type.id','article_image.type_id')
                 ->where('type', $type);
}
```

Then you can do `$article->articleimage()->type('script')`.

Comment: I added a goal to this please see above

Comment: The statement here will only get images that have a image_type = 'script'. Try it. If your result is different, we need more information here, because your problem may be other than your query.

Comment: the issue is that I don't understand the basics of eloquent and accessing the image data based on the type value associated to it. What information would you like and I will provide it.

Comment: Updated. Take a look.

Comment: OK so this is what I was thinking but not quite I have added an update of what I got back above.

Comment: which model did you put the scope?

Comment: I put it in articleimage and got that response which is expected since its linked to articleimagetype by article_image_type_id but I want to access articleimage by the articleimagetype name field

Comment: if i changed it to say where('article_image_type_id', '1') this would work as a scope within articleimage but i want to say where('name', 'script')

Comment: have you tried `return $query->where('article_images.name','=',$query)`?

Comment: Yes but it doesn't see that it exists at that stage, I've updated it and did kind of get a better result but I am missing the type name being returned

Comment: Now I see your `name` column is in a different table. Updated, take a look.

Comment: These tables are connected by belongsTo, hasMany, etc. there isn't a way to do what you just did above with eloquent and the connections that foreign keys create? Is this the table tree issue I keep seeing online A->B->C and accessing A or B based on C?

Comment: So FYI your item worked!! thanks so much and I am marking as fixed but could you answer my question in the comment above? I had the understanding that situations like these are easy with eloquent but iot seems like you have to fall back on laravels based DB query engine to solve this problem.

Comment: Eloquent doesn't execute `JOIN`, it does a lot of `WHERE IN` from multiple tables. This is the way to do. You can use Eloquent, lose some performance, but still.. you can try the way you show in your `UPDATE`, but add a `with` clause: `$article->with('articleImages','articleImages.articleImagestype')->whereHas('articleImages.articleimagetype', function($query){` Not sure if it will work, but give a try.